# Metodo Configure en .net 6 ya que este no tiene archivo startup.cs

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

estoy cambiando el codigo de .net 5 al 6 tengo el siguiente codigo en .net 5:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env,**ApiDbContext db**)
    {
        
        app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "EjemploApiRest.Webapi v1"));
        }

        **db.Database.Migrate();**
        app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

lo que esta en negrilla no sé como colocarlo en .net 6...

lo que he intentado en .net 6 es:

```
var app = builder.Build();
var conf = app.Configuration;
conf.Database.Migrate();
```

efectivamente sale error... alguna sugerencia??

Comment: Si estás migrando, deberías tener program.cs y startup.cs a menos que migrar le llames a construir todo desde cero e ir pasando código conforme avances.

Comment: Esto podría ser de ayuda: https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/0e0372c3c1d895c3ce195ba983b1e03d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la pagina de Jason Watmore encontre la solucion

```
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
 var dataContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
 dataContext.Database.Migrate();
}
```

[net 6 execute ef database migrations from code on startup](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2022/02/01/net-6-execute-ef-database-migrations-from-code-on-startup)

Comment: ¡Excelente!, recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada haciendo click en el check del costado, de este modo colaboras a mantener la buena salud del sitio por efecto de preguntas resueltas. Saludos.